# ADF Self hosted integration runtime choose main node

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

In the ADF Self Hosted integration runtime, I have two nodes. Can I choose one IR node as the main and the other as secondary? If there is a third one, can I choose the order in which each one is picked? I could use low tier VMs for second and third hence the question.

Comment: I think we cannot.There are only two types of roles in a multi-node self-hosted integration runtime – dispatcher and worker. All nodes are workers, which means they can all be used to execute jobs. There is only one dispatcher node, which is used to pull tasks/jobs from cloud services and dispatch them to different worker nodes. The dispatcher node is also a worker node. There are no role of master and slave.

Answer (score 0):

I think we cannot,the nodes of the self-hosted integration runtime in ADF will automatically switch when one node stops. We can reference this [article](https://www.powerupcloud.com/azure-data-factory-setting-up-self-hosted-ir-ha-enabled/) to setting up Self-Hosted IR HA enabled. But the role of the node is automatically switched.

After that, we can run a test.
At first, Self-Host is a **Dispatcher/worker** role.
[image]

When I stop Self-Host manually, we can see Selft-Host2's role switched to **Dispatcher/worker** automatically.
[image]

Comment: Can we conclude the first one created is the main one?

Comment: We can see the first one created is the main one. If the first one stopped, the second one will be the main one, even if the first one restarted.